# Tube amps on voltage regulator

Tags: amperage, tube

I have one basic question, because I don't know much about tube amps. I live in a country where during winter, voltage can be from time to time low (around 160V-180V). I decided to keep my amp safe using an automatic voltage regulator, which keeps it around 220V-230V, which is good. Can those devices do any harm to a tube amp?

I also noticed that when there are voltage oscillations during the day, the amp tends to be slightly lower sounding. Is that normal behavior for tube amps?

Comment: What is `coz` ?  It is not an English word.

Comment: what does this mean? `lower sounding`

Comment: sorry for my bad english. coz=because

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tubes tend to be robust. Undervoltage will not hurt, unless some grid bias (control grid, suppressor grid) enters a region where excessive grid current can be drawn.

And yes, when the power line voltage drops a lot, your regulator will drop out
of regulation, and the reduced tube plate voltage results in lower audio power.

Comment: I'd like to add one thing: If the main voltage drops, so does the heater. This can harm the cathodes over time.

Comment: ty very much!!!

Comment: It has like more sag - less headroom if you know what i mean.